# Таблица Excel в Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.6

Нужно написать программу в Python  для перевода «символических» координат Excel в линейные координаты. например: В Excel внутренняя ячейка A1 соответствует ячейке в строке 0 и столбце 0. Примеры что программа должна выдавать:
Введите координаты:(пользователь вводит координаты) CD 17 i программа дает 
Строка: 16 Колонка: 81

Script:

```
cells = [input("Indique as coordenadas : ")]
from re import match as rematch
for cell in cells:
    cell = cell.lower()
    m = rematch('([a-z]+)([0-9]+)', cell)
    if m is None:
        from sys import stderr
        print('Invalid cell: {}'.format(cell), file=stderr)
    else:
        col = 0
        for i,ch in enumerate(m.group(1)):
            row = (ord(ch)-96) - 1
            col+=(26**i)*row 
        row = int(m.group(2))-1
        print('Linha: {}, Coluna: {} '.format(row, col))
```

Проблема в том, что правильно подсчитывает координаты только от А до Z, а начиная с АА, АВ ... и дальше, не подсчитывает колонны.